# Merge most of the IDE-to-AHCI questions

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

As it stands, we have *at least* **six** questions dealing with enabling AHCI support on an IDE mode Windows installation:

1. [How to get AHCI support on an IDE Windows 7 installation?](https://superuser.com/questions/618261/how-to-get-ahci-support-on-an-ide-windows-7-installation/618262) (~150 views, asked July 2013)
2. [How can I enable AHCI on a SATA drive after installing Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/110927/enabling-ahci-on-sata-drive-in-windows-7) (~1700 views, asked February 2010)
3. [Can I change from BIOS IDE mode to AHCI mode at any time?](https://superuser.com/questions/225189/can-i-change-from-bios-ide-mode-to-ahci-mode-at-any-time) (~14,000 views, asked December 2010)
4. [Getting an IDE mode installation of 7 to run in AHCI mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/450513/getting-an-ide-mode-installation-of-7-to-run-in-ahci-mode) (~500 views, asked July 2012)
5. [How can I enable AHCI mode after Windows Vista install in IDE mode and before/for Windows 7 clean install?](https://superuser.com/questions/94223/how-can-i-enable-ahci-mode-after-windows-vista-install-in-ide-mode-and-before-fo) (~16,000 views, asked January 2010)
6. [Change from IDE to AHCI after installing Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/471102/change-from-ide-to-ahci-after-installing-windows-8) (~35,000 views, asked September 2012)

Windows 8 made significant changes to the IDE-to-AHCI process, so #6 should obviously stay as a standalone question.

My proposal for dealing with #1-5 would be to *merge* them (answers and all) into either #2 (which has extremely general wording) or #3 (which has a high view count). I feel that #5 isn't a good candidate because it's rather verbose and not sufficiently general, and #4 and #1 are just low view count dupes of #2/3 (but with quality answers*).

Could an appropriately-privileged community member please consider taking action on this?

<sub>*Disclaimer: I answered #1, so I have a stake in keeping my answer on the site. That said, it *is* unique from the other answers in that it offers a link to Microsoft's automated Fix-It tool.</sub>

Comment: My first thought on this is the following blog post: [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication)

Comment: Note: _some_ duplication. I think the degree of duplication here is a little excessive.

Comment: I closed them as duplicates of #2 for now. Didn't have the energy to judge such a merge :P